How do I read the cycle counting register on Windows ARM64
Just bought a windows laptop sporting the Snapdragon Elite processor and trying to get acquainted with the ARM instruction set via some C-code. First attempt is to read from the cycle counter register needed to optimize my algorithms but I can figure it out.
This link states:
Cycle counter
ARM processors running Windows are required to support a cycle counter, but using the counter directly may cause problems. To avoid these issues, Windows on ARM uses an undefined opcode to request a normalized 64-bit cycle-counter value. From C or C++, use the __rdpmccntr64 intrinsic to emit the appropriate opcode; from assembly, use the __rdpmccntr64 instruction.
#include <iostream>
#include "stdint.h"
#include "arm64_neon.h"
#include "intrin.h"

int main()
{
#ifdef _M_ARM64
    unsigned __int64 cc = __rdpmccntr64();
#endif
}

but I'm getting this error message:
*identifier "__rdpmccntr64" is undefined    *
The code is compiled in Visual Studio 2022 with ARM64 as target processor!
Any idea what is causing this error? Pointers to example code will be appreciated.

Defined for arm but not arm64.  Hmm.

thanks for your question.
You should be able to read the cycle counter value from the use model (Exception Level0).
We used Visual Studio to read the contents with the following code:
#include "arm64intr.h"
#define ARM64_PMCCNTR_EL0       ARM64_SYSREG(3,3, 9,13,0)
__int64 ret;
ret = ReadStatusReg(ARM64 PMCCNTR_EL0);
Please let me know if you have any other questions.
